# How the output of the below code becomes 1 need good explanation

Tags: java

The result of the above program is 1 but I am not sure how its giving the result of 1. someone pls explain this to me.. it was asked in one of the interview I had for automation

```
    a = 1111;
    a = a-- -a;
```

Comment: Try to reformat the code to find the operators and look up the operator precedence and evaluation order. What you do you think `a--` and `-a` are doing?

Comment: @passer-by this seems to be an interview question which I guess is aimed at showing some level of language understanding. Not sure I'd use it though - at least I'd probably accept "I don't care because you shouldn't ever code like this" as the best answer :)

Comment: @Thomas - thanks for the enlightenment; now I look back at the question, I see my reading skills should have been tested at interview :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at first break this statement and try to understand what's going on

```
a = a-- -a;
```

So you must be aware with operator precedence

so here what's going on is

at first a-- is getting evaluated as it is postfix decrement

***Postfix decrement operator means the expression is evaluated first using the original value of the variable and then the variable is decremented(decreased).***

so the expression is becoming like this

```
a = 1111 - 1110
so a = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. a-- is 1111 , after the evaluation is 1110
2. -a is -1110, the value of before

so 1111 - 1110 is 1

Answer (score 0):

a=a-(a-1)
this means a=1111-(1110)=1  //a-- is applied after operator